# Defining custom MPI type based on preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, types, mpi

Just a quick question regarding MPI datatypes, I want to offer both single and double precision support which I do through preprocessor directives. For my sequential program I do

```cpp
#if defined(USE_SINGLE_PRECISION)
  using floatT = float;
#elif defined(USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION)
  using floatT = double;
#endif
```

Naively I though I could do something similar for MPI, i.e.

```cpp
#if defined(USE_SINGLE_PRECISION)
  using MPI_FLOAT_T = MPI_FLOAT;
#elif defined(USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION)
  using MPI_FLOAT_T = MPI_DOUBLE;
#endif
```

It seems though, that `MPI_FLOAT` and `MPI_DOUBLE` are not quite what I would expect them to be. Is there an easy fix for this? I am probably just missing something here.

Comment: Giving user type or variable names the `MPI_` prefix is generally discouraged as it may clash with future additions to the standard or result in mysterious errors with current implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_FLOAT` and `MPI_DOUBLE` are **not** types (like `float` or `double`), but "variables" of type `MPI_Datatype`, so the C++ `using` syntax cannot be using here.

FWIW, `MPI_Datatype` is an opaque type that is implemented as

- an `int` in MPICH and its derivatives (and `MPI_FLOAT` is a hardcoded integer)
- an opaque pointer in Open MPI

A portable way to solve your issue could be to

```
#if defined(USE_SINGLE_PRECISION)
  #define MPI_FLOAT_T MPI_FLOAT
#elif defined(USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION)
  #define MPI_FLOAT_T MPI_DOUBLE
#endif
```

Note there might be a more C++ish way of doing it, but I am not the right person to advise on that.